# Java Fibonocci sequence BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger, fibonacci

I am trying to run a program which find the nth sequence in the Fibonacci series; however, the issue is, I want to implement BigInteger in it so it can run values of 1000 or even more.

Is there any way to efficiently add it in?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
public class fib {   
//Arkham
    /*public static BigInteger fibonacci2(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    }
    return fibonacci2(n - 2).add(fibonacci2(n-1));
}*/

    public static int Fibonacci(int n) {

        int num = Math.abs(n);
        if (num == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (num <= 2) {
            return 1;
        }

        int[][] number = { { 1, 1 }, { 1, 0 } };
        int[][] result = { { 1, 1 }, { 1, 0 } };

        while (num > 0) {
            if (num%2 == 1) result = MultiplyMatrix(result, number);
            number = MultiplyMatrix(number, number);
            num/= 2;
        }
        return result[1][1]*((n < 0) ? -1:1);
    }

    public static int[][] MultiplyMatrix(int[][] mat1, int[][] mat2) {
        return new int[][] {
                { mat1[0][0]*mat2[0][0] + mat1[0][1]*mat2[1][0], 
                  mat1[0][0]*mat2[0][1] + mat1[0][1]*mat2[1][1] },
                { mat1[1][0]*mat2[0][0] + mat1[1][1]*mat2[1][0], 
                  mat1[1][0]*mat2[0][1] + mat1[1][1]*mat2[1][1] }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int n = reader.nextInt();

        System.out.println("\n" + Fibonacci(n));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with using `BigInteger`?

Comment: Idk how to implement it, or use it in this specific situation. when i put in 100, i should get 354224848179261915075 

instead I get -980107325

Comment: Replace all `int` with `BigInteger` and all the operators with `Biginteger` method calls.

Comment: I get 27 errors lol, 2 different types, some are that int cant be converted to big integer, 

and * is a bad operant type

Comment: Yep, reread my previous comment. You should have no `int` and no numbers that are not in `BigInteger` constructor or array index and no `*`, no `<=`, no `<` no `>`

Comment: wait, so how would i call the method? something like BigInteger.multiply?

(sorry, im very slow lol)

Comment: Exactly. There are methods for all the other operators as well.

Comment: FWIW, note that "fast doubling" is *much* faster than matrix exponentiation, to calculate a big fibonacci number. I tested both extensively, both in Java, and with my own (Delphi language) BigIntegers. https://www.nayuki.io/res/fast-fibonacci-algorithms/FastFibonacci.java. Note that current Javas use Karatsuba and Toom-Cook algorithms for fast multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you replace `int` by `BigInteger`you should do some changes, however, I changed your code and came up with a something like this :

```
   public static BigInteger FibonacciB(int n) {
    final BigInteger one = BigInteger.ONE;
    final BigInteger zero = BigInteger.ZERO;
    final BigInteger two = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(2));
    final BigInteger minusOne = one.negate();

    BigInteger num = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(n));

    if (num.equals(zero)) {
        return zero;
    } else if (num.compareTo(two) <= 0) {
        return one;
    }

    BigInteger[][] number = {{one, one}, {one, zero}};
    BigInteger[][] result = {{one, one}, {one, zero}};

    while (num.compareTo(zero) > 0) {
        if (num.mod(two).equals(one)) result = MultiplyMatrixB(result, number);
        number = MultiplyMatrixB(number, number);
        num = num.divide(two);
    }

    if (num.compareTo(zero) < 0)
        return result[1][1].multiply(minusOne);
    return result[1][1];

}
```

// the matrix mutltiplier method :

```
  public static BigInteger[][] MultiplyMatrixB(BigInteger[][] mat1, BigInteger[][] mat2) {

    return new BigInteger[][]{
            {(mat1[0][0].multiply(mat2[0][0])).add((mat1[0][1].multiply(mat2[1][0]))),
                    (mat1[0][0].multiply(mat2[0][1])).add((mat1[0][1].multiply(mat2[1][1])))
            },
            {
                    (mat1[1][0].multiply(mat2[0][0])).add((mat1[1][1].multiply(mat2[1][0]))),
                    (mat1[1][0].multiply(mat2[0][1])).add((mat1[1][1].multiply(mat2[1][1])))
            }
    };
}
```

I hope this would help you

Answer (score -1):

Is java the correct tool for this? Perhaps [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) would work better:

```
  tailrec fun fibonacci(i:BigInteger, current:BigInteger=zero, next:BigInteger=one):BigInteger {
    return if (i == zero) current else iterate(i - one, next, current + next)
  }
```

(taken from https://github.com/russel/Fibonacci/blob/master/Kotlin/src/main/kotlin/uk/org/winder/maths/fibonacci/fibonacci.kt)

Comment: Any language that has operator overloading will work better.